# problem to access my phpmyadmin error 500

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I am trying to access my phpmyadmin from the web  url: myip/phpmyadmi, but it shows me an error 500, look at my site I know that the database and domain is working well the bad thing is that I do not have access to my database from phpmyadmin, I have already restarted the apache and this does not show any error.
thanks

i have  Ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: read the apache error log. What is the exact error(s)? Is mysql started?

Comment: mysql is started, and apache no show error

Comment: If you see no 500 error in your apache log you haven't enabled it or aren't looking hard enough.